# How can I split a JPG into Multiple JPG’s automatically?

Tags: image-editing

Right I have been given the task by my company to complete the receipt procedure for our expenses.

I want to find a way to take a photo of say 8 receipts and then import it to a program which can then split these into individual images. The crop will be the same every time as the camera/receipts will be in the same place?

Has anyone got and  ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Imagemagick's [convert](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#crop) command-line tool has a `crop` option which can do that

> -crop geometry
>
> If the x and y offsets are omitted, a set of tiles of the specified geometry, covering the entire input image, is generated. The rightmost tiles and the bottom tiles are smaller if the specified geometry extends beyond the dimensions of the input image.

See http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_equal

or you can perform 8 individual crop operations if the spacing/location or sizes of the receipts are not regular

Answer (score 1):

Try [Photoscape](http://photoscape.org/ps/main/index.php), it's splitter does what you require.